# Databinding-Classes aren't generated any more

Tags: android-studio

I had a working project in Android-Studio, including Databinding. That eleminates some possible sources of error. ;-)

Then I decided to get my feet wet with Kotlin and began to migrate some classes from Java to Kotlin.
Unfortunately I also klicked to update Android-Studio to 3.4 in the middle of this process. So now I have many moving parts ...

Now after some editing, when I try to compile my app, the databinding-classes are not generated any more. Usually this is a problem of missing getters or setters or something like this. But currently I have no compiler errors that indicate such problems. Only all the references to my BR. class are red as this class is not generated.

In the layout-files the getters and setters from the data-variable are not shown - so there is a problem already there.

The build-log tells me to check the log for details, but I can not find any log with error-messages that could lead to a solution.

Android-Studio 3.4, mixed Java/Kotlin sourcecode
Besides those missing BR class, I have no other compilation errors at the moment.

I checked the raw gradle output and also tried to run those steps with the more verbose output - no luck.

Maybe this is related:
- I also have problems to edit my existing layouts with constraint-views. Somehow the constraints are read-only.
After some fiddeling around I managed to get one layout back to read-write mode. Not shure what I did to accomplish this ...
- Also I have the problem that Android-Studio "remembers" the last project and mixes the configurations from the last project with that of the current one. To fix this I have to delete the .idea folder in the project ... After that I can work with my project until I change to another or open a second one in parallel ... :-/

In order to get logs I also changed to generate the binding-classes by the compiler instead on the fly by Android-Studio - no luck.

As this is an installation with some history, I also tried to delete the configuration-files from Android-Studio - also no luck.

Clean- and Rebuild Project, Restart Android-Studio, Invalidate Caches ... all that tried without success.

Currently I am out of ideas where to look. Maybe somebody out there has a tip for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the source of my problems!
After many attempts to find an error in my code or maybe in Android-Studio (also downgraded to 3.3 and tried the current 3.5 canary version) I decided to strip down the code to the max.

So I created a new project. In that project I created 2 observable classes and copied the minimal code from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#observable_objects.
I created one class in java and one class in Kotlin (with an index-Number at the properties so that I could see which properties are generated in the BR class).
Only the properties from the Java-class were generated in the BR class, those from the Kotlin class were missing. No error messages besides the missing BR-properties were generated. :-(

With this information I started a new research and finally found, that for Kotlin currently the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` was missing in the project build.gradle file.
Once I added this, also the properties from the Kotlin class were added to the BR class.
Some (older) articles also add `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:x.x.x"` to the dependencies, but with the latest compiler I got null-pointer exceptions. Seems that this component is already referenced somewhere else, because it is not necessary (any more).

I also added this to my other project and now those BR-properties are also present there. So I am confident to have found the answer to my question and can now focus on bugfixing my app.

Answer (score 0):

if you use imports in xml like

```
<import type="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

you have to delete it because android studio is imported automatically.

ref :

[Just as in managed code, java.lang.* is imported automatically.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports_variables_and_includes)